# CORS is blocking response for no reason

Tags: javascript, browser, cors

I am making POST request to my server and browser is blocking response with CORS policy (missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header), but when I request the same url via Postman the header is there. This are my response headers from Postman:
[image]

And this is browser (chrome in this case) error when I try to do POST request:
[image]

What it's going on?

Comment: You show response headers for Postman request and error message for browser request. According to the latter, headers are not the same.

Comment: @Álvaro González do you know where the problem is?

Comment: Response doesn't pass access control check because there isn't any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the response?

Comment: There is, I am sending it. You can see it in postman.

Comment: Chrome does not get the headers from Postman, it makes its own connections to the server. What are the headers that Chrome gets?

Comment: The problem was that POST request with content response is non-simple request and browser is making preflight OPTIONS request before POST. So I added new server route for this and allowed all origins methods and headers. Now it is working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case of non-simple request, browser make preflight OPTIONS request to the same url to check if the server allows cross-site requests. So adding new route for OPTIONS requests where I allowed all CORS restrictions solved the problem.

```
...
if (webServer.method() == HTTP_OPTIONS) {
        webServer.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        webServer.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        webServer.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        webServer.sendHeader("Timing-Allow-Origin", "*");
        webServer.send(204);
    } else {
        ...
```